# invalid syntax in running flink 1.12.0 wordcount example?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am working on the first flink wordcount example from https://github.com/uncleguanghui/pyflink_learn.

My environment is flink 1.12.0 and ubuntu, the flink is running in the background.

The wordcount example is fairly simple.

```
import os
import shutil
from pyflink.table import BatchTableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings
from pyflink.table import DataTypes
from pyflink.table.descriptors import Schema, OldCsv, FileSystem

env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_batch_mode().use_blink_planner().build()
t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=env_settings)

dir_word = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'word.csv')

t_env.execute_sql(f"""
    CREATE TABLE source (
        id BIGINT,     -- ID
        word STRING    -- word
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 'file://{dir_word}',
        'format' = 'csv'
    )
""")

dir_result = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'result.csv')

if os.path.exists(dir_result):
    if os.path.isfile(dir_result):
        os.remove(dir_result)
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(dir_result, True)

t_env.execute_sql(f"""
    CREATE TABLE sink (
        word STRING,   -- word
        cnt BIGINT     -- cnt
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 'file://{dir_result}',
        'format' = 'csv'
    )
""")

t_env.execute_sql("""
    INSERT INTO sink
    SELECT word
           , count(1) AS cnt
    FROM source
    GROUP BY word
""")
```

running the code with command

```
flink run -m localhost:8081 -py batch.py
```

however a problem occurs that

```
# flink run -m localhost:8081 -py batch.py
  File "batch1.py", line 24
    """)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException
    at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:743)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:971)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1047)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1047)
```

which the error points to this part of code

```
t_env.execute_sql(f"""
    CREATE TABLE source (
        id BIGINT,     -- ID
        word STRING    -- word
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 'file://{dir_word}',
        'format' = 'csv'
    )
""") // issue to happen
```

anyone could spot out what is the solution in this?

Answer (score 0):

Try use the table API version, which he quoted. if worked, means your python version is low. also make sure you install pyflink with pip install apache-flink. Finally u can ask him directly with issues, he answers very fast. I'm also working on his examples and learn pyflink stuffs, the api updates very often, make sure use the same version as well :)